# Print generic variable with println!()

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a single linked list in rust and I have a problem when I want to print generic T varible with println! function. I try to use std::fmt::Display and std::fmt::Debug, but it does not work and I do not know how to asign a type to generic variable. This is my code:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>
}

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Link<T>
}

impl<T: Ord> Node <T> 
{
    fn new(value: T, next: Link<T>) -> Self {
        Node {value: value, next: next}
    }
    
    fn check_and_put(&mut self, value: T) 
    {
        if (self.next.is_none()) {
            self.next = Some(Box::new(Node::new(value, None))); 
        }else {
            if (compare(&value, &self.value)) {
                let mut aux: Link<T> = None;
                self.next.take().map(|node| {
                    aux = Some(node);
                });
                self.next = Some(Box::new(Node::new(value, aux)));
            }else {
                self.next.as_mut().map(|nod| {
                    nod.check_and_put(value);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self, value: T){
        if !self.next.is_none() {
            let mut aux: Link<T> = None;
            self.next.as_mut().map(|node| {
                if (&node.value == &value){
                    node.next.take().map(|nod| {
                        aux = Some(nod);
                    });
                }else {
                    if (!node.next.is_none()){
                        node.delete_node(value);
                    }
                }
            });
            if (!aux.is_none()){
                self.next = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    fn see_values(&self) {
        println_T(&self.value);
        if (!self.next.is_none()){
            self.next.take().map(|node| {
                node.see_values();
            });
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord> List<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        List {head: None}
    }
    
    fn add_element(&mut self, value: T) {
        if (!self.head.is_none()){
            self.head.as_mut().map(|node| {
                node.check_and_put(value);
            });
        }else {
            self.head = Some(Box::new(Node::new(value, None)));
        }
    }

    fn delete_node(&mut self, value: T) {
        if (!self.head.is_none()){
            let mut aux: Link<T> = None;
            self.head.as_mut().map(|node| {
                if (&value == &node.value){
                    node.next.take().map(|nod| {
                        aux = Some(nod);
                    });
                }else {
                    if (!node.next.is_none()){
                        node.delete_node(value);
                    }
                }
            });
            if (!aux.is_none()){
                self.head = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    fn see_values(&self){
        if (!self.head.is_none()){
            self.head.take().map(|node| {
                node.see_values();
            });
        }
    }
}

fn println_T<T: Ord>(x: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn compare<T: PartialOrd>(a: &T, b: &T) -> bool {
    if (a > b){
        true
    }else {
        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.add_element(1);
    list.add_element(4);
    list.add_element(2);
    list.delete_node(2);
    println!("finish");
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0277]: `T` doesn't implement `Debug`


--> single-list.rs:114:22
    |
114 |     println!("{:?}", x);
    |                      ^ `T` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
113 | fn println_T<T: Ord + std::fmt::Debug>(x: &T) {
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error; 14 warnings emitted
```

Comment: You just need to specify that T is Debug: `fn println_T<T: Ord + Debug>`. (this must be added everywhere you use T)

Comment: The "help: consider further restricting this bound" hint in the error message already told you what you could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your types implement `Debug`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>
}

type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Link<T>
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug> Node <T> {
...
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug> List<T> {
...
}
```

And then bind it to your method, notice that in this case  you do not need `Ord` but just `Debug` (which is the only trait used in this case):

```rust
fn println_T<T: Debug>(x: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d42018ba67d0463da596e6ddc1341030)

Note: You would just need to use the **derive** in your structs in case you want to actually print a debug representation for the whole struct (Otherwise you could skip it).

Comment: Could also implement `Debug` iff `T: Debug`, to avoid only being able to use `Debug` structures.

Comment: [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7f521ec26bf9bbcc4f1a5425390c280)

Comment: @Masklinn, absolutetly, good point.